# Read data from com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed

Tags: java

How can we read the data from com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed in java

Comment: welcome to SO.post the question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The [`SyndFeed`](http://www.javadocexamples.com/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed.html) class provides lots of methods for reading the feed metadata.  And to fetch the associated content, you get and iterate over the links, and fetch them with `HttpClient` or `URL.open()` or something like that.